# What causes Ubuntu to become randomly laggy and not fix until I restart?

Tags: kernel, performance

I can use the computer for 2 hours without a problem, then when I do any random memory hungry action (Youtube Video, starting many application simultaneously) the computer becomes very slow and stays like that even if I kill many processes.

I don't know what causes this and even the Gnome System Monitor shows normal memory and CPU usage.

Restarting the X session doesn't fix it and the only way to get my computer back to normal is with a system reboot.

I'm Using Ubuntu 12.04 with XCFE.

How can I detect the source of this behaviour?
 And how can I fix sluginess without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, I concluded that the error is some incompatibility with the kernel 3.x, I had the same error in Fedora Live, Ubuntu Live...

#### Solution

<strike>I don't have the time to troubleshoot this issue and play with th system until it works fine, so I installed Debian Wheezty which uses Kernel version 2.x.</strike>

#### Edit

Without noticing it, I was using the wrong power adapter for my computer (65W instead of 90W). One day my computer was lagging and I removed the card that goes to the wall from the adapter, leaving the adapter connected to the computer and suddenly the computer works fine again, this is when I started suspecting the adapter.